# Trying to change background of the website from the color black to an image

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am having an issue with the background of the website I am trying to make, the background is currently the color black but I would like to change it to an image background. I tried putting the background element in the body tag but it messed up the format of the website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some Website</title>
    <link rel="icon" href= "Logo.png" type="img/SVG" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</head>
<style>
    body {margin:0;
    background-color: black}
    .socialmedia {
        position:fixed;
        right:150px;
        top:35px;
        transform:translate(0,-50%);
        display: flex; /* add this */
        align-items: center; /* add this */
    }
    .preorder button {
        background-color: white;
        border: 0;
        height: 35px;
        width: 110px;
        margin-left: 35px;
    }
    .footer {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        margin-top: 319px;
        background-color: black;
    }
    </style>

<body>
    <div class = "Coming Soon" style = "background-color: black; color: white;" >
        <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/ComingSoon.html"><h1 style = "text-align: center; font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large; font-style: italic">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
        <style>
            a{text-decoration: none;
            color: white;}
        </style>
        <div class="socialmedia">
            <a class = "Facebook">
                <img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/09/facebook-icon-preview-1.png" width="50px" height="50px">
            </a>
            <a class = "Instagram">
                <img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/Instagram-logo.png"  width="50px" height="50px">
            </a>
            <a class = "Youtube">
                <img src = "https://images.seeklogo.net/2016/06/YouTube-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px">
            </a>

        </div>
        <p style = "font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large; text-align: center; margin-top: 300px">Website currently under development. Kickstarter launching soon!</p>
        <div class = "footer" style = "background-color: black; color: gray;">
            <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/ComingSoon.html"><img src="Logo.PNG" style = "margin-left: 40%; width: 130px; height: 80px"></a>
            <p style = "font-family: Verdana; font-size: small; padding-left: 40%;">2017 Some Company LLC | City State somewebsite.com All Right Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the background-color set in the body and within `<div class = "Coming Soon"`. I simply removed the background attribute within the div and changed the background-color to background-image in the body. The image I used seems to be fine. Here's a pen with the changes http://codepen.io/bungeedesign/pen/VpjQyg

To use your image simply change the image path/url here `background-image: url("http://www.hbc333.com/data/out/80/47919123-flat-wallpaper.png");`

Comment: Is there a way for me to use a downloaded image since I don't have a domain name or hosting yet to set the background image's url.

Comment: I also tried this url: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/08/00/28/roadway-1081736_1280.jpg It worked but it added some part of the image to the right side of the background again.

Comment: To use an image you have locally you need to put its path in. e.g. background-image: url("image.png"); change the image.png to what your image is called, you'll also have to make sure you get the images path depending on where you have saved it locally, for example, it could be photos/image.png. As for the photo that you used it will repeat as the images resolotion is too small and won't fill the browser window. You can stop it from repeating by using this background: url("image.png") no-repeat fixed center; it will also center the image.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the no-repeat fixed center

Comment: I've updated the pen - http://codepen.io/bungeedesign/pen/VpjQyg with the image. I managed to find a high res version of it.